# Is it usefull to have both tags 'datastax' and 'datastax-enterprise'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags

On questions related to tag [cassandra](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cassandra), people tag often [datastax](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/datastax) and [datastax-enterprise](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/datastax-enterprise) ([example](https://serverfault.com/questions/793252/how-to-log-gc-seperately-from-system-log-in-cassandra)). I wondered if there a real difference between those two tags, and if one of them should be dropped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not adverse to doing that and making [datastax](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/datastax) (the company) a [synonym](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) for  [datastax-enterprise](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/datastax-enterprise) (currently their main product) .

Users with [sufficient reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) can are encouraged to propose and create that synonym here: https://serverfault.com/tags/datastax-enterprise/synonyms and it will pop-up in the review queues, allowing the community to decide.

Status: **completed**

```
Merge Results
updating post history, 12 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 12 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 6 rows affected
updating Documentation tag proposal commitments, 0 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [datastax-enterprise] and [datastax] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym datastax -> datastax-enterprise was approved!
```

Comment: Alternatively: if there are a couple of up-votes on this answer, I or another moderator can also take care of that.

Comment: [tag:datastax-enterprise] is a product and [tag:datastax] is a company, couldn't the latter be dropped as I doubt people ask questions about a company but rather a product. Or at least I'd make the other way around you suggested on the anwser: make [tag:datastax] is synonym of [tag:datastax-enterprise].

Comment: I'm up for that! And edited the question accordingly